# NSCoder issue on macOS 10.13.2

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have

```
CGFloat     m_pattern[8];
NSUInteger  m_count;
```

and the code

```
m_count = 2;
[coder decodeArrayOfObjCType:@encode(CGFloat) count:m_count at:m_pattern];
```

started crashing on 10.13.2 with the message:

> [_NSKeyedCoderOldStyleArray initWithCoder:]: unable to decode element in array of size (4) and count (2)

Why does it tell that array has a size 4?

`sizeof(m_pattern) / sizeof(m_pattern[0])` gives 8. It worked correctly on 10.13.1.